# Select from 3 joined tables with condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, group-by

I have four tables:

request:

```
id----salesid--custid---serial-----active
=======================================
1-------2-------1--------13221-------1
2-------1-------2--------15422-------1
3-------1-------3--------11233-------1
4-------2-------1--------11342-------1
```

salesid is foreign key from emp table and we don't need any thing from employee table except the emp id so its not important to show its details

custid is foreign key of customer id

serial is the serial of that request

active is flag for delete

requestcondition:

```
id-----requestid-----requestcondition 
======================================
1--------1-------------pending
2--------1-------------installation pending 
3--------2-------------pending  
4--------1-------------completed
```

and

customer:

```
id------name
============
1-------aaaa
2-------bbbb
3-------cccc
```

I want to select last condition added for specific request and the name of the customer and request serial according to the salesid column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select r.id, rc.id, c.name, r.serial, rc.requestcondition
    from request r
    inner join customer c on c.id=r.custid
    inner join requestcondition rc on rc.requestid=r.id
    inner join (
       select max(id) as rcid
        from requestcondition
        group by requestid
    ) latest on latest.rcid=rc.id
```

This will give the latest status of all requests.  If you need just the latest status for one request, you would need to add a where clause at the end.

Comment: it gets error "12:37:25 select c.name, r.phone, rc.requestcondition from request r inner join customer c on c.id=r.custid inner join (     select max(id) as id     from requestcondition     group by requestid ) rc on rc.requestid=r.id LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'rc.requestcondition' in 'field list' 0.001 sec"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT Id=scope_identity();
```

Or

```
LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Through this you can get the last inserted Id and after getting  last condition, Implement joins.Read about it on [this Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).